# Is there a surjective homomorphism from $(\Bbb{Q},+)$ to $(\Bbb{Z},+)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

Consider the groups $G = (\Bbb{Q},+)$ and $H = (\Bbb{Z},+)$. Is there a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $H$? If not, how can I prove there isn't?

I considered a homomorphism that rounds up or down but I saw these operations are not "friendly" with the addition.

Comment: Suppose $f(r)=1$ for some $r\in \mathbb Q$.  What is $f\left(\frac r2\right)$?

Comment: @lulu I saw the prove considering f(r/2) = f(r)/2 = 1/2 but I don't understand why the first equation must be true. The definition I learned in my lecture and the definition on wikipedia suggest the homomorphism must be compatible under the group operation which is addition in our case. So why do we expect the homomorphism to  be compatible under multiplication here?

Comment: Nobody said anything about multiplication.  $1=f(r)=f\left(\frac r2+\frac r2\right)=f\left(\frac r2\right)+f\left(\frac r2\right)=2f\left(\frac r2\right)$

Comment: $2f(1/2) = f(1/2)+f(1/2) = f((1/2)+(1/2)) = f(1)$ so $f(1/2) = \frac{1}{2}f(1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\varphi: G\to H$ be a homomorphism.

If $\varphi(g)=1$, then

$$\begin{align}
1&=\varphi\left(\frac{g}{2}+\frac{g}{2}\right)\\
&=\varphi\left(\frac{g}{2}\right)+\varphi\left(\frac{g}{2}\right)\\
&=2\varphi\left(\frac{g}{2}\right),
\end{align}$$

but then $\varphi\left(\frac{g}{2}\right)\notin\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 5):

Not only is there no surjection, there is no  nontrivial additive map $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Note that for every $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and every positive integer $n$, there exists an element $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $nr=q$. This fact respected under a homomorphism, since $nf(r)=f(rn)=f(q)$. (This means that the additive group of rationals is *divisible*; homomorphic images of divisible groups are divisible).

So the image of any $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ must be an integer $a$ with the property that for *every* positive integer $n$, there is an integer $b$ such that $nb=a$. The only such integer is $0$ (in which case $b=0$ as well), so an additive map $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ must send everything to $0$.